# Drupal Commerce Set Order Total Rules

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-commerce

I have Tried to Recalculate Order Total Using the rules which is not happening

Here is what i did

**Rules Event** - **Calculating the sell price of a product**

**Rules Action** - **Set Data value**
       on this action i setted the updated price to the commerce order
       (Ex)
          the original price - 16
          the updated price - 15.20

**Rules Action** - show message on site (Which shows the updated commerce order for testing)

Here is what i get
     The Order of the price displaying on site from **show message on site** action is

- 15.20
- 16.00

  which means the updated 15.20 is overwritten by the old price 16.00

I don't no from where the overriding happens

Answer (score 0):

Order Total can changed through line items

Commerce line items modules have rules action "Multiply the unit price by some amount"

You need used this action.

set the value of Amount 0.95 (16.00 x 0.95 = 15.20)

Set the value of PRICE COMPONENT TYPE "Discount"